# JavaFX Update Issue?

Tags: java, javafx, refresh

I'm working on a game in JavaFX, and right now I'm trying to create a loading screen, since loading the assets takes some time. I've created a LoadingPane class that displays several progress bars, and I know for sure that it works. However, in the below code, the loading pane will not be visible until after the loadAssets function, even though I'm adding it beforehand. When I run the below code, I get a blank stage for the time it takes for the assets to load, and then a screen with the completed progress bars.

I haven't been able to find anyone with similar issues, or any sort of refresh or update function to force the scene to display the loading pane before continuing with the program.

Note: I've deleted some irrelevant code setting up keyboard input handling.

```
public class Main extends Application{
    Pane root = new Pane();
    Scene mainScene = new Scene(root, Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH, Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT, Color.BLACK);

    static LoadingPane loadingPane  = new LoadingPane(3);
    private static int loadingIndex = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(Constants.DEBUG_MODE)
            System.out.println("WARNING: Game has launched in debug mode!");
        launch(args);
    }

    public static void updateProgress(double percent){
        loadingPane.setBarLength(loadingIndex, percent);
    }

    public static void loadAssets(){
        RoomLoader.createRooms();
        updateProgress(1.0);
        loadingIndex++;

        ProjectileLoader.load("imgs/projectiles/");
        ProjectileLoader.load(Constants.BATTLE_IMAGES_FILEPATH);
        updateProgress(1.0);
        loadingIndex++;

        BattleLoader.createBattles();
        updateProgress(1.0);
        loadingIndex++;
    }
    public static void updateProgress(double percent){
        loadingPane.setBarLength(loadingIndex, percent);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        //root.getChildren().add(new javafx.scene.image.ImageView(new Image("imgs/loading.png")));
        root.setLayoutX(0);

        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.toFront();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Branch");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        //primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("core/imgs/soul/red.png"));
        //This allows the closing of the primaryStage to end the program
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        root.resize(Constants.WINDOW_WIDTH, Constants.WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("imgs/icon.png"));

       //End GUI setup

        //The problem lines
        root.getChildren().add(loadingPane);
        //refresh root?
        loadAssets();
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Working Code**
For anyone who arrives here with a similar issue, below is the code I used to get this to work:

I replaced this:

```
//The problem lines
root.getChildren().add(loadingPane);
//refresh root?
loadAssets();
```

With this:

```
root.getChildren().add   (loadingPane);

Task<Integer> loadingTask = new Task<Integer>() {
    @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
        loadAssets();

        return 1;
    }
};

loadingTask.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>(){
    @Override
        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t){
            loadingPane.setVisible(false);
            load(); //note: this function sets up the actual game
                    //updating the GUI, adding game elements, etc
        }
    });


new Thread(loadingTask).start();
```

I can't say that this is the best way to go about this, but I can say that it works. Good luck!

Comment: You need to run the update method in a separate thread.

Comment: That did it, thank you! Do you know what's causing that?

Comment: Huh. I thought that the way the code was working was [some code -> call to update GUI -> GUI updates -> back to where you were in the code]. Is that not how FX works?

Comment: I added an answer, you can choose that as an accepted answer.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX application runs on specific thread called Application Thread, in other to make GUI responsive while doing some expensive operation, like in your case loading assets, you will need to load assets on another `Thread` that you create yourself or you can use `Task` which is one of JavaFX classes meant to be used in such use cases.

I suggest you to read about `Task` in [official javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that that is how FX worked. I assumed everything ran on the same thread. That explains why you need a start function in your main class. Thanks!

Comment: Rip, when you answer in the comments but someone else answers first so your answer is second

Comment: @JacobB. I don't want to argue but I didn't steal your answer, you just said that he needs another thread which is partially correct and on top of that you didn't have any explanation of why.

Comment: Thats valid. I don’t want to argue either. Enjoy your success.

Comment: Also i never mentioned stealing you answer btw

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate thread for the update method.

Code runs in a linear fashion, one bit of code runs then the next. With a separate thread, the two “lines” of code can run side by side. The process runs and the GUI updates at the same time.